# TYPO3 News Lightbox

Tags: typo3, bootstrap-modal

TYPO3 6.2.13, News (tx_news) 3.2.2,  Detail views.

Is there a setting to have pop-ups for any image in the detail views?

I see I may use TS `plugin.tx_news.settings.detail.media.image.lightbox.enabled`, but I am not sure about what it is supposed to output.

Moreover, is there a way/instructions to integrate something like [lightbox](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox) into templates for News views?
thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add configuration in your TypoScript setyp (fancybox example):

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.detail.media {
 image {
        lightbox {
            enabled = 1
            class = fancybox
            width = 200
            height = 200
            rel = fancybox[myImageSet]
        }
      }
 }
```

And in your JS file add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

You will have to include appropriate JS files.

Comment: Yes, thanks. With lightbox instead of fancybox, it works too, but I need to insert in the template something like _data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="{mediaElement.title}" data-footer="{mediaElement.alternative}"_. Could I get them from TS instead? Also, where is the documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think there is implementation for data attributes. You can find documentation on this link: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Introduction/Index.html
If you want to add data attributes, you can do it by overriding default template which is located on path: news/Resources/Private/Partials/Detail/MediaImage.html

Answer (score 0):

It helped me 3 years later. but there is something wrong in your code, detaildetail ... better for other people are also looking for that is, only one detail :-)

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.detail.media {
  image {
    lightbox {
        enabled = 1
        class = fancybox
        width = 200
        height = 200
        rel = fancybox[myImageSet]
    }
  }
```

}